# Using inline javascript to change text-box value with with 2 decimal places

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have 3 text boxes, the first textbox for total, second for the service fee and the third for the grand total.

The problem is in the service fee. it is working but i have to change it to only display 2 decimal places.

Here is the code:

```
<p><span><?php echo $this->lang->line('Deposit Amount:');?></span> $ 
<input name="total" class="total" size="10"
    value="<?php if(isset($amount)) echo $amount; else echo set_value('total');?>"
    onKeyUp="document.depositAmount.service_fee.value = 
        document.depositAmount.total.value*(<?php echo $commission?>/100);
        if(Number(document.depositAmount.total.value)){
            document.depositAmount.grand_total.value =
                parseFloat(document.depositAmount.service_fee.value) +
                parseFloat(document.depositAmount.total.value)
        } else
            document.depositAmount.grand_total.value=0" 
    type="text"/>
```

Comment: Please format your code in a way that doesn't make peoples eyes bleed in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use `toFixed()` method:-

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n=num.toFixed(2); 

result:- 5.57
```

Replace your code like :-

```
document.depositAmount.grand_total.value=parseFloat( document.depositAmount.service_fee.value).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(document.depositAmount.total.value).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: my inline function it's not working